# What is the default value of sqlite3_busy_timeout?

Tags: sqlite, transactions

This seems like it should be really easy to find out, but I don't see it documented anywhere.  If I open a sqlite connection and begin a transaction without specifying a timeout by calling `sqlite3_busy_timeout`, what default value is used?  Or will this somehow cause undefined behavior?  The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) of this method doesn't say.

My specific use case is the version bundled with iOS, but I'm guessing the answer is pretty much the same across platforms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If neither `sqlite3_busy_timeout()` nor `sqlite3_busy_handler()` are set and a writer is active then `step()` returns `SQLITE_BUSY` immediately.

Note: In some cases `SQLITE_IOERR_BLOCKED` is returned
See also: [Register A Callback To Handle SQLITE_BUSY Errors](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_handler.html) in the second paragraph where it states

> If the busy callback is `NULL`, then `SQLITE_BUSY` or `SQLITE_IOERR_BLOCKED` is returned **immediately** upon encountering the lock. If the busy callback is not `NULL`, then the callback might be invoked with two arguments.

Comment: Now only `SQLITE_BUSY` is left in the cited paragraph if you open that link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

`sqlite> PRAGMA busy_timeout = 30000;`

It sets the `busy_timeout` pragma to 30 seconds.

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout

From what I've read (the default is 0) which I assume is either immediate busy response or unlimited waiting. Docs don't say. However I am seeing when multiple processes write to db, they will sometimes throw a BUSY error.